# I can not upload a file using PHP on Linux

Tags: php, apache

I´m running PHP 8.2.9, Apache 2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) on RedHat 8.7.

Somehow, I´m not able to upload the file to a specific folder under my project.

```
This this the folder where the project is running /opt/policy_editor/www/html
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache   62 Mar  2 14:51 depreceated_files
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache 4096 Mar 13 15:39 img
drwxr-xr-x. 11 apache apache 4096 Aug  4 10:04 inc
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache 8646 Aug  4 09:49 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache   19 Mar  2 14:51 info.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache 5401 Jul 28 09:38 login.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  101 Mar  2 14:51 logout.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  395 Mar  2 14:51 mail.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache 1485 Mar 13 15:39 maintenance.php
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache 4096 Jul 28 09:38 sql_updates
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache    6 Aug  4 10:11 tmp
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache    6 Aug  4 09:47 uploads
```

I have all the right permission in place, but still not able to move the file to uploads.
I have confirmed the upload file is saved on /tmp on system folder

But I get these errors

Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/test.pol): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/policy_editor/www/html/inc/admin/admin_post_commands.php on line 487

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpV2j8Vv" to "uploads/test.pol" in /opt/policy_editor/www/html/inc/admin/admin_post_commands.php on line 487

I have seem similar errors on this channel, most solution points to change permission.
Unless I´m missing something, permission seems to be not my case.
I also have tried to move the application under /var/www, but I get the same issue.

Comment: Is your target folder `/opt/policy_editor/www/html/uploads` (as the `ls` output suggests) or `/opt/policy_editor/www/html/inc/admin/uploads` (as the error message suggests)? Is your PHP process running with `apache` user credentials? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Hello @ÁlvaroGonzález, the file should be moved /opt/policy_editor/www/html/uploads, this is the expected place.
Yes I have enabled the  SELinux and it´s running apache credentials.

Comment: Then the path in your code is wrong. Other things look okay at first sight.

Comment: The path is correct,
`
#Upload Policy and Guide file
if ( isset($_POST['uploadPolicyFile'])){
    $add_newcommands='class="selected"';
    $file_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $path =  __DIR__ . "/uploads/".$file_name;

    $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ($fileType != "pol"){
        die("File not valid.");
    }

read_file($path);

    echo '<div style="color: blue" id="resultUploadPolicy">Upload completed. Check the logs.</div>';

    
}
`
This code I force to save on /opt/policy_editor/www/html/inc/admin/

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have an issue about **Relative & Absolute** file paths.

Test with absolute path and with

```
__DIR__ . "folder/file.ext";
```

Comment: Using __DIR__ or document root does, I have the same issue.

Comment: The issue is now resolved.
The problem was regard the SELinux, I used this link as a reference 
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/
Thanks to the ones trying to help me on this issue.